# При перетаскивании элементов списка порядок остается прежним

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

Пишу свой ToDo List на Android (Kotlin) с сохранением в базе данных. Реализовал возможность перетаскивать элементы, меняя их местами. Однако, есть проблема. Для удобства сделал гифку:

1. есть список с названиями: 1, 2, 3.
2. меняю 1 и 2 местами.
3. кликаю на 1, чтобы отредактировать.
4. возвращаюсь к списку, но порядок вернулся к тому, который был до перетаскивания.

Если кто-то сталкивался с таким, буду рад помощи.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что ваша проблема состоит в том, что вы неправильно храните сам список. Я конечно могу ошибаться т.к. вы не приложили кода, но смею предположить, что ваш список храниться (или получается) где-то или в самом адаптере или `Activity`.

Если вы хотите иметь актуальное состояние вашего экрана, то вам нужно позаботиться об актуальности данных. Самый простой способ это создать какую-то сущность (`Presenter`/`ViewModel` и т.п.) в которой будет храниться состояние экрана, в вашем случае это ваш список в нужном порядке.

Условно вы вошли на экран:

1. Загрузили данные и передали их в ваша `Adapter`.
2. После чего вы поменяли их местами. И тут важный момент, вы должны сделать замену не в адаптере, а в вашем `Presenter`/`ViewModel` и после чего заново обновить адаптер. Тут стоит реализовать [DiffUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil), чтоб всякий раз не обновлять весь список.
3. После того как вы вернулись на предыдущий экран вы просто снова подгружаете состояние из `Presenter`.

В целом это же можно сделать и через базу данных, а если вы используете **RX Java** то вы вообще можете просто подписать ваш адаптер на изменения в БД. И все изменения гонять через БД, так вы будете получать актуальное состояние даже после выгрузки приложения из памяти.

Но суть в том, что ваш **UI** не должен ничего знать о логике получения данных, он должен быть максимально тупым и единственной его ответственностью должно быть: *"Рисование самого себя"*.

В то же время слой с логикой и данными не должен зависеть от вашего **UI**, и хранить в себе актуальное состояние независимо от того что и где открылось.

Comment: Сергей, спасибо за ответ! Я как раз храню данные в бд и viewmodel в виде livedata. Во фрагменте подписан на livedata. Проблема, мне кажется, в том, что в бд нельзя задать порядок хранения. То есть данные оттуда всегда подтягиваются в порядке id элемента.

Comment: Код можно посмотреть здесь https://github.com/apolloandroid/MyToDoList/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mytodolist

Comment: Сергей, вы посмотрели код? Есть ли что добавить?